# Gmaps4rails Polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

I'm very new to rails and have no clue how I may generate the correct javascript for creating polygons in gmaps4rails.  I was able to display google maps with markers but am lost as how to generate the matching json code as shown in https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Polygons.  I would like to generate everything through rails and not hardcode any javascript.

Heres my test code for drawing only the first polygon in the location_data model.
The latitude and longitude attributes are serialized.

Controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
skip_load_and_authorize_resource
 skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
def index

LocationData.find_each do |location|

@polygons = Array.new(LocationData.count,Array.new)

location.latitude.each_index do |index|
@polygons[0] << { :lat => location.latitude[index], :lng =>location.longitude[index]}
end


    end
#@polygons.to_json

respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.json { render json: @polygons }   

end
end
end
```

Javascript generated looks like

```
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.polygons = [[{"lat"=>42.31276, "lng"=>-71.03645}, {"lat"=>42.35653, "lng"=>-71.06754}, {"lat"=>42.45453, "lng"=>-71.7856}]];
Gmaps.map.polygons_conf.fillColor = "#000";
Gmaps.map.create_polygons();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
 window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
```

View

```
<%= gmaps({
       "polygons"    => { "data" => @polygons    , "options" => { "fillColor" => "#000" } }
     })
 %>
```

Comparing it with the code on the wiki I notice that the javascript has => in it for some strange reason.

Update

I was missing a line in my code

```
@polygons = @polygons.to_json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing one line of code in my controller.

```
@polygons = @polygons.to_json
```